# How can I fix this Visual Studio bug?

Tags: visual-studio

[image]

There are some functions when I make couple of new lines after them, I get this white line between the functions. Does someone know how to fix this? It happens to me a lot, and I searched for this bug on the internet but didn't found any answer.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about the white box around method definition?

Comment: @TroyTurley no, the white line in the left side, between the two last method definitions

Answer (score 0):

Go to:
Tools->Options->Text Editor->General

Uncheck "Show Structure Guidlines"

Comment: Do you want outlining, the plus & minus signs that let you hide code, to function?

Comment: Yes I want to keep this functionality